# Equivalent to SAS If then do in R

Tags: r, sas

Is there a smart alternative way to the "if then do" datastep of SAS?

The situation: I have one condition

```
if year == 2022
```

and for the TRUE case I want to set values in three columns

```
A = 20
B = 30
C = 40
```

and for the else part e.g. all three columns shoud have the value 0 (or each could have an other value). I'd searched over and over but haven't found a smart and easy way to do it (like it is in SAS).

What is the smartest way to solve this problem (in dplyr).

Thanks

Comment: To get good answers here, you need to give more R details - the SAS bit seems entirely irrelevant.  What structure is your data now?  Data Frame?  Vector/Matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a data frame named `data` with the columns `year`, `A`, `B`, and `C`. Here are a couple options:

```
# base R 1
rows = data$year == 2022
data[, c("A", "B", "C")] = 0
data[rows, "A"] = 20
data[rows, "B"] = 30
data[rows, "C"] = 40

# base R 2 - more concise
rows = data$year == 2022
data[, c("A", "B", "C")] = 0
data[rows, c("A", "B", "C")] = list(20, 30, 40)


# dplyr 1
data = data %>%
  mutate(
    A = ifelse(year == 2022, 20, 0),
    B = ifelse(year == 2022, 30, 0),
    C = ifelse(year == 2022, 40, 0)
)    

# dplyr with lookup table - 
#  generalizes nicely to more variables
lookup = data.frame(
  year = 2022, A = 20, B = 30, C = 40
)

dat = data %>% mutate(across(c(A, B, C) ~0)) %>%
  rows_update(lookup, by = "year")
```